# Replace labels that round to 0.0 with strings in geom_text in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a heatmap with geom_tile in R. I've figured out everything except how to change labels that round to 0.0 with strings such as "d" (for detected).

The relevant part is:

```
+ geom_text(data=subset(MELTEDL3, value !=0),aes(fill=value,label=format(round(value*100, 1), nsmall = 1)), size=3)
```

Which grabs all the values from MELTEDL3 that are not zero. Next, for the labels, the values are multiplied by 100 and the labels are displayed with 1 decimal even if the values round to e.g. "30" (so instead, "30.0"). The thing is, a few values round to less than 0.1 and are displayed as 0.0. It would be easy to get rid of them by specifying a different subset, however, I would like to include the observations, only not as "0.0" but as "d".

edit. 
For example:

```
L3.txt
Taxon   A30 A29 A20
ABCD    0.001   0.0004  0
DADD    0   0.04    0.000001
GHKJ    0   0.07    0

L3 <- read.table('L3.txt', header=T)
MELTEDL3 <- melt(L3, id=c("Taxon"))
L3PLOT <- ggplot(MELTEDL3, aes(Taxon, variable)) + 
geom_tile(aes(fill=value, colour=value)) + 
scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0),limits=c("ABCD","DADD","GHKJ")) +
scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) + 
scale_fill_gradient2(low="white",mid=muted("blue"),high="red", space="rgb", midpoint=0.5) +
geom_text(data=subset(MELTEDL3, value!=0),
       aes(fill=value,label=format(round(value*100,1),nsmall=1)),size=3)
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little hackish, but this works:

```
geom_text(
  data=subset(MELTEDL3, value != 0),
  aes(
    fill=value,
    label=ifelse((fmt <- format(round(value*100,1), nsmall=1)) == "0.0", "d", as.character(fmt))
  ),
  size=3
)
```

Cleaner would be to define your own `format` function that wraps this logic, but basically it's the same thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. For whatever reason, this didn't work. However, now knowing the syntax, I was able to make it work as such:######### geom_text(data=subset(MELTEDL3, value != 0),aes(fill=value,label=ifelse((round(value*100,1) < "0.1"),"d",format(round(value*100,1),nsmall=1))),size=3)#########sorry about lack of linebreaks, don't know why adding two spaces or <br> does nothing for me.